# Add Post Format Support to Twentyeleven Child Theme

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven, post-formats, add-theme-support

On a Twentyeleven child theme's functions.php file I attempted to add video post format support using:

```
add_theme_support('post-formats', array( 'aside', 'chat', 'gallery', 'image', 'link', 'quote', 'status', 'video', 'audio'));
```

...adding the 'video' format to the array.  But it would not work until I deleted the function in the parent theme. Obviously, when the theme is updated and functions.php is overwritten, I will lose the change.

Whats the best way to avoid this and add support to my child theme?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running your code with a lower priority:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_twentyeleven_setup', 20 );

function my_twentyeleven_setup(){
  add_theme_support('post-formats',  array( 
     'aside', 
     'chat', 
     'gallery', 
     'image', 
     'link', 
     'quote', 
     'status', 
     'video', 
     'audio',
  ));  
}
```